# How to Adjust Background Position in ImageBackground Component (React Native)?

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I have an image like this as an asset `seats.png` (180 x 36 px) each "seat" is a 36x36 px image:

[image: This is My Image]

My code:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground 
      style={styles.redSeat}
      source={seatsPng}
      resizeMode="cover"
      >
      </ImageBackground>
</View>

import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

export default EStyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#333',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
  },
  redSeat: {
    width: 36, 
    height: 36,
    left: 0 // I want to show only red seat on the display
  }
});
```

How to make it so I can display the red seat, yellow seat, or purple seat, just by adjusting the image offset, like background-position in HTML/CSS? The code above only display a green seat.

PS: I searched the React-native GitHub page, I can't believe that this issue was marked closed with no solution from the developer. So I'll open this thread if maybe there'll be a solution in the future. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12347

Comment: Were you able to figure out?